# Скрытие элемента с анимацией по событию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Написал вкладки, получилось их скрывать по клику, но не получилось прикрутить анимацию появления активной вкладки.

Для саморазвития хочу прояснить пару моментов:

1. Как правильно прикрутить анимацию появления активной вкладки?
2. Хотелось бы увидеть, как опытные написали бы js код в настоящей задаче...

```js
$(function()
{
    $('.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link').click(function()
    {
        // основной контейнер вкладок
        var tab_container = $(this).parents('.tabs');
        // настоящая вкладка
        var tab_link = $(this);
        // настощий контент вкладки
        var tab_content = tab_container.find('[data-tab-content-name="' + tab_link.attr('data-tab-link-name') +'"]');

        // если вкладка уже активна, то манипуляции не проводим
        if(tab_link.hasClass('active'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        // если вкладка не активна
        else
        {
            var tab_link_old = tab_link.parents('.tabs__nav').find('> .nav__item > .nav__link.active');
            tab_link_old.removeClass('active');
            tab_link.addClass('active');

            var tab_content_old = tab_content.parents('.tabs__content').find('> .content__item.active');
            tab_content_old.removeClass('active test');
            tab_content.addClass('active test');
        }

    });
});
```

```css
*
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: initial;
  margin-bottom: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
  margin-right: initial;
  -webkit-padding-start: initial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link
{
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link.active
{
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.tabs > .tabs__content > .content__item
{
  display: none;
}

.tabs > .tabs__content > .content__item.active
{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--такой id для идентификации именно этих табов, т.к. их может быть на странице десяток другой-->
<div id="tabs-6543" class="tabs">

  <ul class="tabs__nav">
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav__link active" data-tab-link-name="tab-1">Ссылка вкладки 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-tab-link-name="tab-2">Ссылка вкладки 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tabs__content">
    <li class="content__item active" data-tab-content-name="tab-1">
      Контент вкладки 1<br>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
    </li>
    <li class="content__item" data-tab-content-name="tab-2">
      Контент вкладки 2<br>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div style="background: #c3e6cb">
Любой другой блок после табов.
</div>
```

**Код анимации:**
Для примера, давайте используем этот вариант анимации...

```
<!--появление-->
transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
transform: translate(0, 0);
opacity: 1;
<!--скрытие-->
transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
transform: translate(0, 50px);
opacity: 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Задача решилась следующим методом:

```js
$('.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link').click(function() {
        // основной контейнер вкладок
        var tab_container = $(this).parents('.tabs');
        // настоящая вкладка
        var tab_link = $(this);
        // настощий контент вкладки
        var tab_content = tab_container.find('[data-tab-content-name="' + tab_link.attr('data-tab-link-name') +'"]');

        // если вкладка уже активна, то манипуляции не проводим
        if(tab_link.hasClass('active'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        // если вкладка не активна
        else
        {
            var tab_link_old = tab_link.parents('.tabs__nav').find('> .nav__item > .nav__link.active');
            tab_link_old.removeClass('active');
            tab_link.addClass('active');

            var tab_content_old = tab_content.parents('.tabs__content').find('> .content__item.active');
            tab_content_old.removeClass('active');
            tab_content.addClass('active');
        }
});

$('.tabs').on('transitionend', '.content__item', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent())
  }
})
```

```css
*
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: initial;
  margin-bottom: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
  margin-right: initial;
  -webkit-padding-start: initial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link
{
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}

.tabs > .tabs__nav > .nav__item > .nav__link.active
{
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.tabs > .tabs__content > .content__item
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50px);
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabs > .tabs__content > .content__item.active
{
  position: static;
  background: antiquewhite;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--такой id для идентификации именно этих табов, т.к. их может быть на странице десяток другой-->
<div id="tabs-6543" class="tabs">

  <ul class="tabs__nav">
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav__link active" data-tab-link-name="tab-1">Ссылка вкладки 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-tab-link-name="tab-2">Ссылка вкладки 2</a>
    </li><li class="nav__item">
      <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-tab-link-name="tab-3">Ссылка вкладки 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tabs__content">
    <li class="content__item active" data-tab-content-name="tab-1">
      Контент вкладки 1<br>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
    </li>
    <li class="content__item" data-tab-content-name="tab-2">
      Контент вкладки 2<br>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.
    </li>
    <li class="content__item" data-tab-content-name="tab-3">
      Контент вкладки 3<br>
      gfjskgdfklgkg  gdfskg;l 43-0 kgop34g-0 ;ldfg 34-igokglpdmf' lg-43
      gdkfmg kdf;jgdf;jgokj fdogm 04-3ti043i tld;fgkld;f 
      gf jdigjdfjgdfklg934t-043i gkodfj-340asvl; 943ti-43ti-034
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div style="background: #c3e6cb">
Блок с текстом после табов.
</div>
```